# Initialise empty object array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to initialise empty object array in TypeScript?

**Code:**

```
let data: [{productID: number, vendorID: number}] = [];
```

**Compilation error:**

```
Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[{productID: number, vendorID: number}]'.
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you have written is a tuple with one-element, try this instead:

```
let data: Array<{ productID: number, vendorID: number }> = [];
```

Alternatively:

```
let data: { productID: number; vendorID: number }[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

defince a type first `Product` then declare an array of that type:

```
interface Product{
    productID: number;
    vendorID: number
}
let data:Product[]=[]
```

Comment: There is no need to separately define an interface

Comment: @HTMHell are you sure?

Comment: yes, look at the accepted answer. that would work just fine